# Parse objects in JSON, and retrieve data

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a variable name "userList".

This variable is a JSON containing a few objects, depending on the amount of users online...

Here is the JSON/variable stringifed: (Contains two users.)

```js
{
  "User1": {
    "ident": "guest#1",
    "username": "Guest1",
    "posx": 2,
    "posy": 10,
    "lineWidth": "1",
    "lineColor": "00baff"
  },
  "User2": {
    "ident": "guest#2",
    "username": "Guest 2",
    "posx": 1,
    "posy": 5,
    "lineWidth": "1",
    "lineColor": "000000"
  }
}
```

How could I log every objects "username" value?
Here's my script:

```js
if (obj.msg === "/log") { //If EventSource's obj.msg ='s ...
  var list = JSON.stringify(userList) //String the variable.
  console.log(list) // Log the objects.
} else {
  console.log("Event msg is not /log ")
}
```

I've tried doing this:

```
console.log(list.username)
```

Comment: what do you expect `list.username` to result in? You have to access the objects by their keys : `list["8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls"].username`

Comment: Is there anyway to parse the objects? & be able to log them like that? console.log(list.username)

Comment: Or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the object's keys and access the username fields like this:

```js
var list = {
  "8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls": {
    "ident": "8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls",
    "username": "Antidote",
    "posx": 1002,
    "posy": 125,
    "lineWidth": "1",
    "lineColor": "00baff",
    "ignore": false,
    "status": "w"
  },
  "1fjw6u6ok8q6jrqcnr47yymbaida2iwp": {
    "ident": "1fjw6u6ok8q6jrqcnr47yymbaida2iwp",
    "username": "from Lehi, United States",
    "posx": 989,
    "posy": 124,
    "lineWidth": "1",
    "lineColor": "000000",
    "ignore": false,
    "status": "w"
  }
}


for (item in list) {
  console.log(list[item]['username'])
}
```

Comment: Nice man, I figured it out a while back ago. Just now seeing these older questions of mine from a while back. Useful & works.

Answer (score 1):

You have a map of two objects, you can only access them using their key. Also, `JSON.stringify` returns a string. To parse a string to from a JSON object, use JSON.parse.

```
if (obj.msg === "/log") { //If EventSource's obj.msg ='s ...
  var list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userList)) // this is not needed your userList is already parsed
  
  // First Approach es5
  for(var key in list){
    console.log(list[key].username); // here is how u can access your name
  }

  // Second Approach es6
  for (const item of list){
    console.log(item.username);
  }
} else {
  console.log("Event msg is not /log ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log()` statement doesn't reference the key despite referencing the value, so it would make more sense to do:

```
console.log(list["8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls"].username);
```

If you aim to get the `username` values of the keys of the objects manually/individually rather than iterating through the `username` instances in the object's keys, you could also use the JSON.parse() method as follows. Make sure your JSON list is a string:

```
var list = '{ "pmicxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls": { "ident": "8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls", 
   "username": "Antidote", "posx": 1002, "posy": 125, "lineWidth": "1", "lineColor": "00baff", 
   "ignore": false, "status": "w"}, "1fjw6u6ok8q6jrqcnr47yymbaida2iwp": { "ident": 
   "1fjw6u6ok8q6jrqcnr47yymbaida2iwp", "username": "from Lehi, United States", "posx": 989, 
   "posy": 124, "lineWidth": "1", "lineColor": "000000", "ignore": false, "status": "w"}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(list);
var username1 = obj["8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls"].username;   // or obj.8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls.username
var username2 = obj["1fjw6u6ok8q6jrqcnr47yymbaida2iwp"].username;   // or obj.1fjw6u6ok8q6jrqcnr47yymbaida2iwp.username
```

Answer (score 0):

To show all the users usernames at once, you can use `Object.values(userList)` to get an array of the objects inside `userList` object then use `forEach` method to loop through that new `array` :

```js
const userList = {
  "8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls": {
    "ident": "8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls",
    "username": "Antidote",
    "posx": 1002,
    "posy": 125,
    "lineWidth": "1",
    "lineColor": "00baff",
    "ignore": false,
    "status": "w"
  },
  "1fjw6u6ok8q6jrqcnr47yymbaida2iwp": {
    "ident": "1fjw6u6ok8q6jrqcnr47yymbaida2iwp",
    "username": "from Lehi, United States",
    "posx": 989,
    "posy": 124,
    "lineWidth": "1",
    "lineColor": "000000",
    "ignore": false,
    "status": "w"
  }
}

Object.values(userList).forEach(i => console.log(i.username));
```

But if you need to get the username from a certain object in `userList`, you'll need to access that object using it name (key) :

```js
const userList = {
  "8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls": {
    "ident": "8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls",
    "username": "Antidote",
    "posx": 1002,
    "posy": 125,
    "lineWidth": "1",
    "lineColor": "00baff",
    "ignore": false,
    "status": "w"
  },
  "1fjw6u6ok8q6jrqcnr47yymbaida2iwp": {
    "ident": "1fjw6u6ok8q6jrqcnr47yymbaida2iwp",
    "username": "from Lehi, United States",
    "posx": 989,
    "posy": 124,
    "lineWidth": "1",
    "lineColor": "000000",
    "ignore": false,
    "status": "w"
  }
}


console.log(userList['8micxp7q5w5tfsrkkw9iys7l2ead7tls'].username);
/** output: Antidote **/

console.log(userList['1fjw6u6ok8q6jrqcnr47yymbaida2iwp'].username);
/** output: from Lehi, United States **/
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that `username` is not an attribute of the `userList` object, so you need to iterate over the `Object` in order to access each user object:

```
for (var ident in userList) {
    if (userList.hasOwnProperty(ident)) {
        console.log(userList[ident].username);
    }
}
```

Also, are you trying access attributes of the String `list`? If you want to access the attributes programmatically you should keep the `Object` as `userList`, because once you call `JSON.stringify(userList)`, you'll get a pretty useless `String` representation of the `Object`.